# Protractor selenium localStorage.clear() is not working with Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Trying to clear localStorage at the start of each test, but it's not working with Internet Explorer 11 (where it works without issue in Chrome/Firefox).

Code we have tried:

```
browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');

browser.executeScript('localStorage.clear();');
```

And:

```
browser.driver.get('javascript:window.localStorage.clear();');

browser.driver.get('javascript:localStorage.clear();');
```

Versions:

- IEDriverServer_2.45.0
- selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0

Searched Google and cannot locate any solution that works.

Any ideas?

**[Edit:]** Note: further things that we have tried -- when we do something like this, localStorage is NOT cleared, however the alert DOES appear:

```
browser.executeScript('javascript:localStorage.clear(); alert("HelloWorld");');
```

So `browser.executeScript` seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried calling it without referencing the window object? The example in the docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288131(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't use one, so maybe it is worth a try?

Comment: @MBielski Yes, same result. localStorage remains uncleared.

Comment: Updated with Edit with more details on where it's failing. executeScript seems to work, but the `localStorage.clear()` command fails.

Comment: You might be having URL problems. LocalStorage is per URL. That being said, the URL value can be spoofed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974811(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Selenium has issues with Internet Explorer 11 browser and fails to execute few things like your `executeScript()` function. [Here are more details of it](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7135). If you have installed latest updates with version KB3025390 of IE11 then uninstall it and try running your code again. Also add your site to trusted sites and then try it. If this doesn't work the [try this solution](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6511#c29).

Comment: It's Windows 7 Enterprise and there was no update #KB3025390. Did already have the trusted site settings however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several hours of debugging, we're unsure why it started working all of a sudden, but looks like it may have needed the following line:

```
browser.get('/');
```

So altogether, the reset should look like:

```
browser.get('/');
browser.executeScript('localStorage.clear();');
```

Comment: I'm not very surprised by this. There are a number of things that won't work until Selenium has loaded the first page.

Comment: @Louis, for some reason it worked in Chrome/Firefox without any problems. And actually, we're not even sure this is the issue we were having, as we tried a whole bunch of things. But we think it may be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we've been successfully using:

```
"use strict";

var LocalStorage = function () {
    this.getValue = function (key) {
        return browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.getItem('" + key + "');");
    };

    this.get = function () {
        browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage;");
    };

    this.clear = function () {
        browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.clear();");
    };
};

module.exports = new LocalStorage();
```

Usage:

```
var localStorage = require("localStorage.js");

localStorage.get();   // this is basically used for testing if local storage is supported 
localStorage.getValue("key_in_storage");
localStorage.clear();
```